# Git plugin for NetBeans 7.0.1 displays unmodified files as modified

Tags: git, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

For some reason the Git plugin (version 0.2.12.42.1) I use for Netbeans 7.0.1 displays all files as modified, with blue filenames. However, the status of unmodified files are displayed as "-/-" as opposed to modified files which show up as "-/Modified".

Why is this and how can I solve it?

Comment: Is this on Windows? What does git itself say is the status? This kind of behavior is sometimes caused by autocrlf or cygwin issues.

Comment: This is indeed on Windows. I'm using msysGit. git itself doesn't list anything incorrectly. CRLF sounds like a probable cause!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use jgit myself, but I've seen reports of various bugs that exist in jgit (which is the backend to nbgit and egit). It appears that jgit does not follow core.autocrlf. See [the bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=301775), which has been open for 2 years. Also [here](http://code.google.com/p/egit/issues/detail?id=54). There are some unofficial workarounds in the bug. The best option is to turn off autocrlf. Once you do so, you may need to delete and check out the files in the working copy to reflect this.

Here we use `core.autocrlf=input` with Unix line endings on windows. The developers using egit have not reported having this problem in that use-case.

Comment: I followed this tutorial, which seems to solve it for me: http://help.github.com/line-endings/